# Create a new NSError in Swift (to reject a Promise from PromiseKit)

Tags: swift, promisekit

I have been trying to use PromiseKit, and I'm stuck at rejecting a promise.

Promise rejection is done either by calling a reject function with an NSError as argument.

```
func getAPromise() -> Promise<Bool> {
    return Promise<Bool> { fulfiller, rejecter in
        let diceRoll = Int(arc4random_uniform(7))
        if diceRoll < 4 {
             // rejecter(?) how do I call this rejection correctly ?
        } else {
             fulfiller(true)
        }
}
```

Simply getting an instance of NSError would help me.

**EDIT**:

```
NSError("somedomain", 123, [])
```

complains with "Extra argument in call".

Comment: When all else fails [read the instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/).

Comment: Oh thanks really helpful and productive! Thanks for the down vote too... Any answer instead of pointing to the doc I just read? In case you are wondering. Yes, calling the constructor of NSError doesn't work, e.g.: `NSError("somedomain", 123, [])`.

Comment: But you never said that.  You described no error (still haven't).

Comment: Neither said I the contrary. I asked how to instantiate an NSError in Swift, because so far I found no way to do it, and so far you are not providing an answer (so I guess you have never done it) so I guess you too, which lead me again to: "Why the down vote?"

Comment: Well, for one, because you didn't show the failing code or the error.

Comment: Ok you have my opinion, I have mine. I was expecting more openness there, maybe I'm wrong, enjoy your day.

Comment: So, tell me -- would you have gotten an answer without posting the failing statement and the error message?

Comment: Indeed not. So tell me, if you are trying to build a reliable professional community do you think that bashing bad practices instead of mentoring is a nice way to foster openness and engagement?

Comment: Was your first response fostering "openness and engagement"?  You came in like a spoiled brat.  Didn't think of your readers (who are not being paid to be your servants) and create a *complete* question which at the very least included the failing code and the error message.  Grow up!!

Comment: (And you've got a rep, so you should know what a proper question looks like.)

Comment: You are right about my question, which doesn't prevent me from being right about comment.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You have two problems in this code:

```
NSError("somedomain", 123, [])
```

- All initialization parameters of `NSError` have [external name](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_313).
- Empty `Dictionary` literal is `[:]`, not `[]`. `[]` is for `Array`

Try:

```
NSError(domain: "somedomain", code: 123, userInfo: [:])
```

Or, if you don't have any `userInfo`, you might want to pass `nil` for it.

```
NSError(domain: "somedomain", code: 123, userInfo: nil)
```

Comment: Would be handy to have the userinfo included